# running code when celery starts in worker mode

Tags: python, celery

I am looking to run some code when a celery worker starts. Not when let's say a task is imported to be used from a client type application.

```py
celery_app = Celery(__name__)
# I want to only create the egine if this file is used by a worker
engine = create_engine(str(POSTGRES_URL))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for worker signals ( https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html?highlight=worker_ready#worker-signals ). It is all nicely explained there. I am guessing `worker_ready` is the one you should look at first.